# Replace only whole words using a dictionary (file)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm pretty new to python so please forgive me,if this is really obvious. I would like to replace all the words in file with alternative words based on a dictionary ( or dictionary file). I've been through a number of other posts and this code ( below) works quite well. However, it will also replace substrings.

```
text = "strings.txt"
fields = {"Cat": "Hello", "Hat": "Goodbye"}


for line in fileinput.input(text, inplace=True):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line:
        continue
    for f_key, f_value in fields.items():
        if f_key in line:
            line = line.replace(f_key, f_value)
    print (line)
```

So, caterpillar will become Helloerpillar and hatemonger will become Goodbyemonger. I would like substrings to be left alone, so only the full words will be replaced. Can anyone advise me on how to do this?

Also.... This is less important but I have also tried to get the script to read the dictionary from a separate file. This isn't so important but it would be nice to have.

I have tried to modify the script in the following way without luck.

```
    import json
  
with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

text = "strings.txt"
fields = data

for line in fileinput.input(text, inplace=True):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line:
        continue
    for f_key, f_value in fields.items():
        if f_key in line:
            line = line.replace(f_key, f_value)
    print (line)
```

any advice that you could provide on either of these problems ( especially the first) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
fields = {"Cat": "Hello", "Hat": "Goodbye"}
s = "This Is A Catterpilar Chatting With A Cat"


s =   ' '.join([fields[w] if w in fields else w for w in s.split(' ')])
```

output:

```
'This Is A Catterpilar Chatting With A Hello'
```

What the line do is split the sentence into words, replace every word by its equivalent if it is in the `fields` dict else leave it as is, then join all words into a new sentence.

For simplicity sake, all words begin with a capital, but you can handle this easily a a second step.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering so quickly. The text I want to replace is a large document of many words and equations, will this solution work for this? Just had a go and found it difficult.

Comment: There is not much processing done here, so it should be ok ! How many words approximately ?

Comment: Oh, maybe 10,000 words.

Comment: Sorry no, Is your suggested edit compatible with an input file? I tried to add your code to my little script but i can't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I got the script working but it doesn't seem to work. I can't add the suggestion to my script ( not sure how) and i can't add my text to your script. Could you suggest how i can integrate what you gave me into my script? Or could you suggest how i can read a file into your little script?

Comment: My variable `s` is your variable `line`, so handle each line like I handled the variable `s`

Comment: Sorry just to check, you don't mean that my variable "fields" is your variable "S"? Also do you mean that each and every line with the variable "line" needs to modified?

Comment: No, our variable fields correspond to the same thing, and each line you read is a sentence you want to modify right ? (s stands for sentence in my answer)